# Express Morgan. Logging to the internal object

Tags: node.js, logging, express

guys. I'd like to use express middleware logging tool 'morgan' and want to change some default behaviour.
As it's said in the documentation (https://github.com/expressjs/morgan/blob/master/README.md) one of the paramateres it takes is "stream" which defines the output. By default it outputs to the node console but we can change it to log to the specified file.

```
// create a write stream (in append mode)
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/access.log', {flags: 'a'})

// setup the logger 
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}))
```

I wonder if there is an opportunity to forward all the logs to the specified object on the server? I mean do something like this:

```
var obj = []
var foo = function(param) {obj.push(param)}
app.use(morgan('combined'), {stream: foo})
```

thanks in advance!